# Unity Firestore - .value of string is alway empty *Bug

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

***Hi,**
I use Firestore everywhere in my app and it works perfectly, but at this one place its is very **WEIRD**, see for yourself below.*

[image: Firestore Hierarchy Screenshoot]

```
    SocialDocumentListener = SocialDocument.Listen(snapshot => {

        Dictionary<string, object> TchatDictionary = snapshot.ToDictionary();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> x in TchatDictionary)
        {
            Debug.Log($"<color=purple>Social/Country/{UserSocial.GetLobbyType()}/{UserSocial.GetLobbyName()} -> Key:{x.Key} / Value:{x.Value}</color>\n");

            if (x.Key.Contains("M_"))
            {
                if (x.Value.ToString().Length >= 22)
                {
                    string stamp = x.Value.ToString();
                    string sPlatform = stamp.Substring(0, 3);
                    string sCountry = stamp.Substring(3, 2);
                    string sTime = stamp.Substring(5, 10);
                    string sColor = stamp.Substring(15, 6);
                    string sMessage = stamp.Substring(21, (stamp.Length - 21));
                    string sName = x.Key.Substring(10, (x.Key.Length - 10));

                    long iTime = long.Parse(sTime);
                    float fColor = ((float.Parse(sColor)) / 1000);

                    NewDataMessage.Add(new Struct_Message(sPlatform, sCountry, sName, sMessage, iTime, fColor));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is the result in the editor, weird that it does it twice but it works! :D.**

```
Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:ID / Value:1

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:Lobby / Value:System.Collections.Blabla

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_34KCY5CSSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214822211000Merci​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_EWS7VVGPSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206202756211000lol​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_4W8Y5R3NPlayer82287 / Value:ANDCA1206213816029000sup​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_YU24X2P4SebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214206211000hey​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_GUPICC36SebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214220211000bye​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_VP8Y7N5QSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214215211000hello​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:ID / Value:1

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:Lobby / Value:System.Collections.Blabla

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_34KCY5CSSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214822211000Merci​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_EWS7VVGPSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206202756211000lol​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_4W8Y5R3NPlayer82287 / Value:ANDCA1206213816029000sup​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_YU24X2P4SebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214206211000hey​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_GUPICC36SebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214220211000bye​

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_VP8Y7N5QSebTHEking / Value:ANDCA1206214215211000hello​
```

**Now here is the result on my phone Android Samsumg S9+**

```
Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_34KCY5CSSebTHEking / Value:

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_EWS7VVGPSebTHEking / Value:

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:Lobby / Value:System.Collections.Blabla

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_YU24X2P4SebTHEking / Value:

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_VP8Y7N5QSebTHEking / Value:

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_4W8Y5R3NPlayer82287 / Value:

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:ID / Value:1

Social/Country/International/Lobby 1 -> Key:M_GUPICC36SebTHEking / Value:
```

**There is a couple of things that are not right here!**

- The order of the debug.log
- Value is empty (When its a string)
- Value is ok (When its a number?!)

I am trying to read the value but it is empty???

So my question is, What am I doing wrong here? how can I get the value on mobile?

**Did some test today:**

So I changed my path from "Social/Country/International/Lobby 1/" to "Social/Lobby 1/"

Worked the first time, but not the second time. I am still having the same bug???

Why when I change the path it works fine the first time?

Comment: Anyone? Does no one have any idea what the bug could be?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/895

Comment: If I go back to version 6.16.1 it works perfectly